# insert data from a DataTable into a dropdown

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, datatable, dataset, datasource

i want to fill a `dropdown` by a `datatable`
bcoz i'v already a method `GetCate()` in bal, which returns `datatable` and now want to dynamically fill the data into a `ddl` with some `datasource` and `databind` script, could it b possible ???

why does not possible to assign a datatable into a dropdownlist???

```
public void BindCateDDL()
{

    DataTable dt = new BALCate().GetCate();        
    ddl_filter_category_id.DataSource = dt;
    ddl_filter_category_id.DataBind();
}
```

**is this a right way to do this ???**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you have to do is to bind the dropdown to your datatable as follows;

```
ddl.DataTextField = "ColumnName1";
ddl.DataValueField = "ColumnName2"
ddl.DataSource = dt;
ddl.DataBind()
```

Answer (score 2):

There's a few ways to do this:

1) Create a new `listItem` in each iteration, add the details and add that to the DDL:

```
public void BindCateDDL()
{
    //DropDownList ddl;
    DataTable dt = new BALCate().GetCate();
    foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
    {
        ListItem l = new ListItem();
        l.text = dr["colForName"].ToString();
        l.value = dr["colForValue"].ToString();
        ddl.items.add(l);
    }
}
```

2) Add the datatable as a data source to the `DropDownList` and set the `DataTextField` and `DataValueField` properties:

```
public void BindCateDDL()
{
    //DropDownList ddl;
    DataTable dt = new BALCate().GetCate();
    ddl.DataSource = dt;
    ddl.DataTextField = "colForName";
    ddl.DataValueField = "colForValue";
    ddl.DataBind();
}
```